# How to combine arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

I have a 3x2x2 numpy array and I want to join another array to it that is 3x2 so that my new array is then 3x2x3. I have been trying with stack and concatenate but I keep getting `ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape`. The existing array is like follows

```
array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[3, 3],
        [4, 4]],

       [[5, 5],
        [6, 6]]])
```

And I wish to join another array that is like so:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

The output would be like so:

```
array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 2., 2.]],

       [[3., 3., 3.],
        [4., 4., 4.]],

       [[5., 5., 5.],
        [6., 6., 6.]]])
```

I am not sure if I have written the output correctly as the way numpy displays matrices with 3 dimnsions confuses me- The result should have the shape(3,2,3). I wish to do this iteratively so that I can keep extending the matrix so that the shape would be (3,2,4) then (3,2,5) then (3,2,6) etc...

Comment: And the desired output is ..?

Comment: You quoted the `stack` error message, but `concatenate` complained `all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`.  Right?  Do you know how to correct that?  How to add a dimension to the (3,2) array?

Comment: Why do you want to do this iteratively?  Why not collect al the (3,2) arrays into a list, and join them with one `concatenate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape the 3x2 array to 3x2x1 and then do `dstack`:

```
a = array([[[1, 1],
            [2, 2]],
           [[3, 3],
            [4, 4]],
           [[5, 5],
            [6, 6]]])

b = array([[1, 2],
           [3, 4],
           [5, 6]])

np.dstack((a, b[...,None]))
#array([[[1, 1, 1],
#        [2, 2, 2]],
#       [[3, 3, 3],
#        [4, 4, 4]],
#       [[5, 5, 5],
#        [6, 6, 6]]])

np.dstack((a, b[...,None])).shape
#(3, 2, 3)
```

Or `np.concatenate` along the last axis:

```
np.concatenate((a, b[...,None]), axis=-1)
```

Comment: Can please you address me to a reference for `b[...,None]`? I tried `b.reshape(3,2,1)`, but seem not working. It seems that just `np.dstack((a,b))` works.

Comment: You can see [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html) where there's a few examples for `np.newaxis` or `None`. and also `b.reshape(3,2,1)` should work the same way as `b[...,None]`